# Is it possible to display text in one cell based on text color from another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So it's sort if reverse conditional formatting I guess?

I'm making a my own spreadsheet to consolidate all my tasks which are listed on our group's tasks spreadsheet. So far, my spreadsheet is working as I intended, except for the status column.

Basically, I want it so when I turn the task green (change font color) on the group's tasks spreadsheet, the cell beside that task on MY spreadsheet will display "Done".

Comment: Can you please share a spreadsheet as example? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions using apps script and run it using Simple Triggers. To create apps script, Go to Tools->Script Editor

**Simple Triggers**

- Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like opening a document, occurs. Simple triggers are a set of reserved functions built into Apps Script, like the function onOpen(e), which executes when a user opens a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms file. Installable triggers offer more capabilities than simple triggers but must be activated before use. For both types of triggers, Apps Script passes the triggered function an event object that contains information about the context in which the event occurred.
  Here is an example on how to modify Google Sheets using Apps Script.

Sample Function:

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onChange(e){
  
  //Select the active sheet
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //Select the active cell
  var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  //Note: I want to input the status next to the task's column
  var taskrow = activeCell.getRow();
  var statusCol = activeCell.getColumn() + 1;
  
  //Check if font color is green then set the status column to Done
  if(activeCell.getFontColor() == '#00ff00'){
       activeSheet.getRange(taskrow,statusCol).setValue('Done');
  }
  //Check if font color is red then set the status column to Delayed
    else if(activeCell.getFontColor() == '#ff0000'){
       activeSheet.getRange(taskrow,statusCol).setValue('Delayed');
  }

};
```

onChange() method can be triggered whenever there are changes done in the sheet's user interface (like font color).

Using the getFontColor() of the Range Class in SpreadsheetApp, you can get font color of the cell in CSS notation (such as '#ffffff' or 'white').

Then you can set the cell value using setValue() of the Range Class in SpreadsheetApp

**To learn more about SpreadsheetApp and its classes, you can refer to this reference:**
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

**To learn more regarding Simple Triggers and Event object:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

---

**To automate the execution of onChange(), you need to add it to your project's triggers**

1. Open current project's triggers using the clock icon beside the play button

[image]

2. Click Add trigger at the bottom right page of your current project's triggers
3. Populate the necessary information and make sure to select "On change" under Select event type option.

[image]

---

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for this answer! One more question though... is it possible to copy the text color of data taken with importrange? For example, if on the other spreadsheet, the text color is red, can the text displayed in my spreadsheet also be red?

Comment: No, it is not possible using importrange(). Importrange() don't import cell format. But it is possible using Google Apps Script. You just need to select the range of cells and get the font color in the other spreadsheet then set the font color in your current spreadsheet. By the way, please feel free to accept  or upvote my answer if you feel it was useful.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer and upvoted but it doesn't show up. Can I ask how to get the font color using Google Apps Script? I should probably make a new question and you can answer there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65081274/14701422 Here's the new question. Could you please let me know how to get started on making the text colors match between spreadsheets? Thanks in advance!